# Parasitic Oscillations

Tags: power, mosfet, transformer

I'm designing an LLC converter circuit. I've conducted simulations, but I have an issue. When I perform switching below the resonance frequency in the LTspice simulation, I observe parasitic oscillations in the transformer input and output graphs. How can I resolve this, and would this issue actually harm my circuit in reality?

[image: oscillogram]

Here is the schematic:
[image: schematic]

Comment: Can you post the schematic image separately? It’s incomprehensible and cut off.

Comment: The schematic is unreadable. Post a full view of schematic as a separate image, as Bryan suggested. Make sure all of the simulation parameters including pulse sources are visible and readable.

Comment: I shared the circuit diagram.

Comment: You need to be unambiguous as to what the waveforms are by placing labels on the schematic so that people know what you are measuring. You also need to show a schematic that properly indicates ground connections.

Comment: Huh, does LT's 1N5817 model really not include breakdown voltage?!

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you meant to say?